# What are the use cases for Infinity in IEEE 754

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm wondering what are the case to be used for `Infinity` under `IEEE-754`? Is it used when overflow (positive infinity) or underflow (negative infinity) occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinity values are returned by some computations, for example `-1/0` and `Math.log(0)` return `-Infinity`.

Symmetrically they can be used in input of computations, for example `2/-Infinity` returns `-0`.

Infinities are also produced when the real value is too big for representation, for example `Math.exp(999)` or `Math.exp(709)+Math.exp(709)+Math.exp(709)`.

But they're also used anytime you need a number greater (or lower) than any other one, or when you want to explicitly refer to an infinity. For example I commonly use numerical ranges (intervals), that is `{min, max}` structures and when a range isn't bound I use infinities, like `{-Infinity, 3.2}`, which could be noted as `]-∞, 3.2]` in Mathematics.

Be careful though that the support of infinities in the JS ecosystem isn't that great. For example JSON doesn't normally support them (but some libraries help in that matter, like [gson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues--) or my own [parseMore](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.parseMore)).

Comment: thanks, what about my this question `Is it used when overflow (positive infinity) or underflow (negative infinity) occurs`?

Comment: thanks, can you also explain what you mean by `any other one` here _But they're also used anytime you need a number greater (or lower) than any other one,_ ?

Comment: @Maximus Suppose you have a class defining several thresholds and you must raise an alert when some sensors return values greater than those threshold (`if (value>speedThreshold) wakeMaster()`). And now you don't care for one of those sensors, then you just set `speedThreshold=Infinity`.

Comment: thanks, you set it to Infinity, so that no number can be greater in 'if'comparison?